# Is there a way to kill STS(Sprint Tool Suite) from Command Prompt?

Tags: shell, cmd, command-prompt, powershell-3.0, spring-tool-suite

I have been trying to close the STS instance open on my desktop. However, it's not getting closed and I can't use Task Manager since I can't see running apps on the Task Manager(seems to be a Windows 10 bug).

Previous to this, I had tried to import an existing maven project as well as create a new maven project on my opened STS. Both operations were unsuccessful.

Upon closing the running instance of STS, have been seeing the following window :

[image: Spring Instance not closed]

If someone could provide either a taskkill command or some other workaround, would appreciate much.
TIA!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as long as you know the exe you can run:
`taskkill /F /IM name.exe`

Or you could find the exe name via `tasklist`

Answer (score 0):

To kill a process by its `PID`, type the command:

```
taskkill /F /PID pid_number
```

To kill a process by its `name`, type the command

```
taskkill /IM "process name" /F
```

Comment: Thanks Ron! I was able to find the process name using tasklist and then the commands helped :)